# Grid to list view ASP.NET MVC Kendo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am very new in ASP.NET MVC and Kendo and need your help.

I need to show the data in both grid and list mode in same page. Please suggest what is the best way/approach to achieve this. Shall i use list and grid view both and make them hide and show when user change this or this can be done via CSS on single, please suggest.

Comment: Your question is too broad - There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done in css because Gridview and Listview are two different js components. I suggest you to use a shared datasource and create two different components [Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ENAXe)

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: productsDataSource,
                        autoBind: false,
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 300,
                        selectable: true,
                        columns: [
                            {field: "ProductName", title: "ProductName"},
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "100px" },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "100px" },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: "100px" }
                        ]
                    });

$("#listView").kendoListView({
                dataSource: productsDataSource,
                template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
            });
```